# Git diff status flags

Tags: git

I need to completely understand git diff's output for creating a "package" of the changed files.
I want to run and parse `git diff old_commit..new_commit --name-status --diff-filter=ACDMRT` (skipping U and X)

From the documentation:

> Possible status letters are:
>
> A: addition of a file
>   C: copy of a file into a new one
>   D: deletion of a file
>   M: modification of the contents or mode of a file
>   R: renaming of a file
>   T: change in the type of the file
>   U: file is unmerged (you must complete the merge before it can be committed)
>   X: "unknown" change type (most probably a bug, please report it)
>
> Status letters C and R are always followed by a score (denoting the percentage of similarity between the source and target of the move or copy).
>   Status letter M may be followed by a score (denoting the percentage of dissimilarity) for file rewrites.

I've checked several big repositories and haven't found any examples of the "M" that *"may be followed by a score"* and I haven't found any "C" at all.
Does "С" also look like the "R" (`R100    path/from/old.file  path/to/new.file`)? Is it possible for me to do any local commit that will show me such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some status letters, and other conditions, can only occur if you select some particular options.

This is case for `C` and `R`: `C` indicates a copy, and copy detection is enabled with `-C` or `--find-copies`, or explicitly disabled with `--no-find-copies`.  Rename detection is enabled with `-M` or `--find-renames` (but is enabled by default in Git version 2.9 and later).

The `-B` (break pairings) option will turn some cases that *would* show as `M` into `D`-and-`A`, if it breaks a pairing.  If a temporarily broken pairing is re-paired, the `M` value will acquire a score, so `M80`, for instance, would require using the `-B` option.

Note that `git diff` uses the user's default configuration: `diff.renames` will affect whether `R` and values show up or not, with the default being "not" in Git predating 2.9 and "yes" in Git 2.9 or later.

> I want to run and parse `git diff old_commit..new_commit --name-status --diff-filter=ACDMRT` (skipping U and X)

The `U` status only shows up during a conflicted merge.  When using `git diff` with two commits specified, as in your example here, it cannot occur.  The `X` status, as the documentation says, indicates a bug in `git diff` and therefore also cannot occur.

It's probably wiser to use `git diff-tree` directly here.  This *does not* obey any individual user's configuration settings, so you control whether `-M` is in effect.  You can choose whether to supply `-B` and/or `-C` options.  If you do not supply any of these, the only possible letter codes are `A`, `D`, `M`, and `T`.  If you do add the break-pairings, find-copies, and find-rename options, you can of course get the corresponding others—and yes, the `C` format matches the `R` format.

You also get the name-and-status (and no patch) by default, so the output is much more suited to your task.  But you do need the `-r` option, probably.

Comment: Thank you very much! If I got it right I can use `git diff-tree f90e7a9..66e8a07 --name-status -r -B` to have only A,D,M,T (single letters without any percentage)

Comment: Using `-B` will *add* the percentage information to some `M` lines. Omitting `-B` won't attempt to break existing pairings and therefore won't add the similarity index (pairing breaking is based on similarity).

Comment: Without `-B` `git-diff` showed `R100 old  new`. First I thought that I have to apply `-B` also for the `git diff-tree`. But as I see now, `git diff-tree` shows 2 separate lines of `D old, A new` without `-B`.

Comment: `git diff` uses your personal `diff.renames` setting which defaults to `true` in Git 2.9 or later (see the answer above). `git diff-tree` *does not* use your personal setting so no matter which way you set your personal setting, `git diff-tree` obeys *only the command line flags*. If you don't enable `-M` you won't get an `R100`.